# Create variable on one conttoller (CI)

Tags: php, codeigniter

i wanna asked something, so I wanna make variable ip, like this code

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
{
  //check for ip from share internet
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
{
  // Check for the Proxy User
  $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
else
{
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

but my problem is I wanna use that variable `$ip` to all public function on my controller (one file controller), how do I make that?

**NOTE:** I use the framework like CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{

    protected $ip;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); //just added this, sorry

        if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){
            //check for ip from share internet
            $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){
            // Check for the Proxy User
            $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        } else {
            $this->ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Your IP is '.$this->ip;
    }

    public function myMethod()
    {
        //you can use $this->ip in here too
    }

}
```

Visit `http://host/path/to/CI/mycontroller/index` to view the output

You can change the visibility of `$ip` if you need to

Comment: Thanks for comment, and it's work!!! Tq again, and sorry for late information update, i was too busy. And tq again :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the controller's constructor.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

```
    <?php
    class Yourconstructor extends CI_Controller {

            public function __construct()
            {
                    parent::__construct();

            private $ip;

            if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
            {
                //check for ip from share internet
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
            }
            elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
            {
                // Check for the Proxy User
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            }
            else
            {
                $this->ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }

            }
    }

    public function index() {

      if ($this->ip == $some_var_posted_or_whatever) {
         // do something here...
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to change this to `$this->ip =...` so that the variable is visible from other methods, and given that the asker is clearly relatively new, I'd add a reference to it in index() to show that it's visible there.

Comment: @ourmandave  i need to use that varibale $ip to other function of the controller. not to be cunstruction function.

Comment: @Wolfzmus You can make $ip a property of the controller and refer to it anywhere as `$this->ip`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @ourmandave like i said i dont use $ip condition but instead variable, can i do that not like if condition? like using data like this ['ip'=>$ip]??